# My UV map on a cube looks OK but only two faces are seen in editor and non in the render

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

With a lot of help on the internet, I managed to UV map a cube to exactly match a texture I have.

[image]

However in the main view window, I only see the texture on two faces (viewport shading set to Texture):

[image]

In the render mode, I see nothing at all, just default material:

[image]

Do I need to turn the UV map into material somehow to apply it to the object? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Did you link the image to the material? Did you assign the material to the faces?

Comment: No I only have UV map, I don't even have a material. I guess I need to turn the UV map into a material right? How can I do that?

Comment: @SUSU yes, that's it. I was confused that I saw texture at some places but not all.